# Running coverage inside virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, coverage.py, python-coverage

I recently stumbled upon some issue with running coverage measurements within virtual environment. I do not remember similar issues in the past, nor I was able to find solution on the web.

Basically, when I am trying to run test suite in virtualenv, it works fine. But as soon, as I try to do it using `coverage`, it fails because of lack of modules it requires. Based on some answer on StackOverflow I checked my script and found out that `coverage` uses different interpreter, even if running from inside the same `virtualenv`.

Here is how to reproduce it:

```sh
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing Setuptools................................................done.
Installing Pip.......................................................done.
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ echo 'import sys; print(sys.executable)' > test.py
(venv)$ python test.py
/home/tadeck/testground/venv/bin/python
(venv)$ coverage run test.py 
/usr/bin/python
```

The question is: how to make `coverage` work with virtual environment seamlessly? I could alter `sys.path` or install required modules system-wide, but there has to be a cleaner way.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on windows, I'm afraid. Coverage works fine. + 1 to help a fellow pythonista in need :)

Comment: Did you try to install the ``coverage`` package in the virtualenv you are creating?

Comment: @Bogdan: It was already there, so I did not try to (re)install it. But when I do `pip install -U coverage`, I get "`Requirement already up-to-date: coverage in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`pip install coverage` in your new venv

```
[alex@gesa ~]$ virtualenv venv
[alex@gesa ~]$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$ pip install coverage
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$ echo 'import sys; print(sys.executable)' > test.py
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$ python test.py
/home/alex/venv/bin/python
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$ coverage run test.py
/home/alex/venv/bin/python
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$
```

Comment: Your solution helped - I reinstalled `coverage` inside virtualenv. It was installed, but somehow the command was overwritten nad was pointing to wrong place. Now it works properly. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I figured having coverage installed globally was enough, but it kept throwing import errors related to the packages installed in my virtual environment, even though I had the virtual environment activated when running coverage...  It seems like coverage should support this (common) use case.

Answer (score 27):

I had to leave my virtualenv after installing coverage and reactivate it to get coverage to work.

```
[alex@gesa ~]$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
[alex@gesa ~]$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$ pip install coverage
(venv)[alex@gesa ~]$ deactivate
[alex@gesa ~]$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: I am sorry, that isn't an answer, that's a bug report for the virtualenv maintainer.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote for this, its exactly what was causing my problem. Upvotes all around.

Comment: @Tritium21 it is an answer, and it's still valid today - just fixed my issue in Python 3

Comment: @jamespo I was unclear 4 years ago... Its not an answer to the question asked.