# Coverage Module Not Found

Tags: python, virtualenv, coverage.py

I am trying to run coverage on a django project inside of a virtual environment and am having some issues with `ModuleNotFoundError`. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959072/running-coverage-inside-virtualenv) I have installed coverage inside of the virtual environment but am finding that different python interpeter are being used with coverage compared to when running the file with python manually.

When running `python manage.py test` the output is:

```
(env) λ python manage.py test
C:\Users\omarh\Projects\hive\hive-proj\env\Scripts\python.exe
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

where the first line is the result of `print(sys.executable)`

However when running `coverage run manage.py test` with coverage 5.0.1 I get:

```
(env) λ coverage run manage.py test
c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\scripts\python3.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 320, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 44, in add_arguments
    test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 301, in get_runner
    test_runner_class = test_runner_class or settings.TEST_RUNNER
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\users\omarh\projects\hive\hive-proj\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hive'
```

the result of running `python` and `python3` in the venv give an indentical response of:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

and running `python3 manage.py test` is successful.

Running with coverage 3.6 installed instead is also successful however that errors with:

```
Exception: Couldn't find chunk @ 330
```

when trying `coverage html`

Any ideas about why this is happening with Coverage 5.0 and how to fix it? Or how to get Coverage 3.6 to build the HTML report?

Comment: This looks like the same problem as https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/862, which I cannot reproduce for some reason.  BTW: why are you trying 3.6? The previous stable version is 4.5.4. If you make sure you use it everywhere, it should be fine.

Comment: Most (all) of the guides I could find for using coverage with django that stated a version used 3.6, so I tried that as a test. 4.5.4 has successfully run and built the html so I'll continue to use this version for now. Thanks.

Comment: You could help the community by adding a reproducible test case to the coverage.py issue....

Comment: The repo this has occurred on is private, will try and recreate error later today I'm a new project to share.